# Where have SDL2 wiki examples gone?

Tags: sdl-2, code-documentation

In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPHKWsZK2Jc&list=PLvv0ScY6vfd-p1gSnbQhY7vMe2rng0IL0&index=10) from about a year ago, there is example code on the SDL_CreateWindow function documentation page. I have seen other posts talking about the SDL examples.

If you look at the documentation now it is the same minus the example code
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_CreateWindow

Am I blind or is there no longer any example code on the SDL2 wiki?
If not, does anybody know what the reasons for removing it are?

I expect that

1. There are some official examples somewhere
2. If they were removed from the official wiki they would at least be placed in a 'legacy' repo or something like that.

A Google (DuckDuckGo) search gives only third party examples and, aside from a few forum posts, no mention of there ever being any examples on the wiki.

Comment: You should probably ask SDL2 developers. Also try https://archive.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2022, the Wiki migrated from MoinMoin to ghwikipp. With that came a host of breaks and bugs. Your issue specifically is covered under issue [#233](https://github.com/libsdl-org/sdlwiki/issues/233).

The [images were also broken](https://github.com/libsdl-org/sdlwiki/issues/162), but that issue shows a workaround for viewing the Wiki in working form: use archive.org on wiki.libsdl.org, not wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2 where it is currently hosted. This gives you your examples back.

[e.g. like this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210211172232/https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)

If you have some sort of MediaWiki viewer program, you can also just pull an [old revision from the Repo](https://github.com/libsdl-org/sdlwiki/tree/386ef37d5d37eaa7b417d2c10cefd597799ac325) and read it offline. Even Github's MarkDown viewer isn't terrible. Caveat that new changes won't be reflected.

They promise us that it will be fixed at some point, and they do seem to be working hard on it. The only hardfix is either to (a) wait, or (b) help them finish their migration.